# Collision detection problem in XNA

Tags: xna

I'm having two problems with my collision detection in XNA. There are two boxes, the red box represents a player and the blue box represents a wall.

The first problem is when the player moves to the upper side or bottom side of the wall and collides with it, and then try to go to the left or right, the player will just jump in the opposite direction as seen in the video.

However if I go to the right side or the left side of the wall and try to go up or down the player will smoothly go up or down without jumping.

The second problem is that when I collide with the box and my key is still pressed down the blue box goes half way through red box and and goes back out and it keeps doing that until I stop pressing the keyboard. its not very clear on the video but the keeps going in and out really fast until I stop pressing the key.

Here is a video example:-
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKLJsrPviYo

and Here is my code

```
Vector2 Position;
Rectangle PlayerRectangle, BoxRectangle;
float Speed = 0.25f;

enum Direction { Up, Right, Down, Left };
Direction direction;

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Allows the game to exit
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        this.Exit();

    KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

   if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
   {
       Position.Y -= (float)(Speed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds);
       direction = Direction.Up;
   }

   if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
   {
       Position.Y += (float)(Speed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds);
       direction = Direction.Down;
   }

   if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
   {
       Position.X += (float)(Speed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds);
       direction = Direction.Right;
   }

   if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
   {
        Position.X -= (float)(Speed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds);
        direction = Direction.Left;
    }

    if (PlayerRectangle.Intersects(BoxRectangle))
    {
         if (direction == Direction.Right)
             Position.X = BoxRectangle.Left - PlayerRectangle.Width;
         else if (direction == Direction.Left)
             Position.X = BoxRectangle.Right;

         if (direction == Direction.Down)
             Position.Y = BoxRectangle.Top - PlayerRectangle.Height;
         else if (direction == Direction.Up)
             Position.Y = BoxRectangle.Bottom;
     }

     PlayerRectangle = new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, (int)32, (int)32);

     base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: If you've managed to solve this, post your solution as an answer and accept it, or accept one of the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look again at your else/ifs:

- regardless of key combination pressed, only **ONE** direction is saved, because you override them. (the last of them in code)
- if left/right direction is pressed collision from the other side(right/left) is always assumed. (if (direction == Direction.Right) => move player to left side regardless where he is)

quick fix: add another direction, so you have one for left/right other for top/down and check from collisions from both directions separately(own intersect code).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is test *how far* the rectangle can move in a direction, then change it. For example:

```
desiredX += speedX * timeSinceLastUpdate;
desiredY += speedY * timeSinceLastUpdate;

desiredRect = new Rectangle(desiredX, desiredY, width, weight);
intersect = Rectangle.Intersect(desiredRect, collider);
collisionWidth = intersect.Width;
collisionHeight = intersect.Height;
correctedX = 0;
correctedY = 0;
// using speed's sign as the direction of travel
//     and correcting in the opposite direction...
if (collisionWidth > 0)
    correctedX = Math.Sign(speedX) * collisionWidth;
if (collisionHeight > 0)
    correctedY = Math.Sign(speedY) * collisionHeight;
PlayerRectangle = new Rectangle(desiredX - correctedX, desiredY - correctedY, width, weight);
```